# Customize basic find display to include membership status

Tags: civimember

When I submit a search via the "Find contacts" menu item, I would like to add our "Membership Status" to the results page. Where do I go to configure that? I can't figure out which report the basic find command is using to display results.

This is CiviCRM 5.24.5 running under Drupal 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just configure that, you will need to develop a little extension to modify the behaviour.

That would mean finding out which search is involved (I think it is BasicSearch) and probably use the *buildForm* hook (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) to add the column and the *searchColumns* hook (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/) to modify the result.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.